# A grammar question about object

Tags: grammar, objects

I've read a sentence.

> But a series of interruptions and heckles showed the uphill task it
> will be to find co-operation.

"the uphill task it will be to find co-operation." is object. But I can't understand this expression. Is "it" a formal subject?

Here is original text. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-64550143 the third sentence.

Comment: No: "the uphill task" is not an object but a preposed predicative complement of "be". Yes: "it" is subject of the subordinate clause "It will be ___ to find cooperation.

Comment: I think the cited example is *very* peculiar phrasing. Normally, I'd expect *a series of interruptions and heckles showed **what an** uphill task it will be to find co-operation.* Or feasibly *...showed **that it will be** an uphill task to find co-operation* OR *...showed **that finding** co-operation will be an uphill task.*

Comment: The uphill task this will be was shown by a series of interruptions and heckles. Easier to grasp as a passive sentence....

Answer (score 0):

"It will be to find co-operation" is a reduced relative clause modifying "the uphill task." The sentence could be written:

> But a series of interruptions and heckles showed the uphill task **that** it will be to find co-operation.

Comment: I would add that the covert relativised element is predicative complement of "be". I wouldn't call it 'reduced', but simply a 'bare' relative, i.e. one where the subordinator "that" is omitted.